# incompatible type C error?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, interrupt

```
uint32 InterruptLatency;
uint8 measurements[32];
char buf[256];
int kernelinterrupt time()
{
fscanf(fp,"%lu", InterruptLatency);  // I am reading the data from kernel which is not shown here
measurements[17] = InterrupLatency;
buf = &measurements;            // I am getting error here as below

// after storing it in buffer I am  sending the data from but to another layer
}
```

ERROR : incompatible type when assigning of type char[256] from type uint8 (*)[32]

could some one help me how to solve this ??

Comment: can you write a function name with space?

Comment: by   buf = &measurements;  what do you intend to do?

Comment: The error message contains all information.

Comment: Please do not change your question after answers had been provided, as this might make some answers ununderstandable. Add modification to your question as updates.

Comment: Referring my comment above, I rolled back the last modification of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you cannot assign arrays. You have to copy the memory explicitly.

Probably you want to do this:

```
memcpy(buf, measurements, sizeof(measurements));
```

But you gave no details about what you actually want to do.

PS: Your `fscanf()` is wrong. It should take the address of the variable that will hold the read value.

And if you use `uint32_t` you should use the `SCNu32` specification, from `<inttypes.h>`, to be sure that you do not break things:

```
fscanf(fp,"%"SCNu32, &InterruptLatency);
```

Comment: Also the `"l"` length modifier implies that on the OP's platform `long`s are expected to be 32bit. Is this the case?

Comment: @alk: what does OP means? Many people write OP. I googled but i didn't get exactly?

Comment: @SGG: OP = Original Post, or Original Poster. It is the first post that originates the discussion.

Comment: @alk: You are right, the right way is to use the macros from `<inttypes.h>`. Corrected.

Comment: I am reading s64 data type value from the kernel. what will be the fscanf for that ?? I forgot to add & in fscanf.

Comment: @user3458454: It is not obvious from your question, that you read 64bit values. Could it be that this is another question? If so, please post this as a new question.

Comment: @user3458454: If the variable is `uint32_t` you cannot hold a 64-bit value. Use `uint64_t` and `SCNu64` for that.

Comment: I asked a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336896/how-to-store-the-variable-values-in-c-program

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a pointer value to an array. You can't do that.

Use memcpy:

```
memcpy(buf, &measurements, sizeof(measurements));
```