# how to store the variable values in c program?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, interrupt, scanf

KERNEL variables :

```
s32 remainder;
s64 quotient ;
```

---

How do you read the above variable values in a C program and store them in below variable?

```
uint32 InterruptLatency;
```

I am reading the time from kernel and it is off the type s32 and s64 as 1.3456;

how to read this on the user side program ??

```
uint32 InterruptLatency;
uint8 measurements[32];
char buf[256];
int kernelinterrupt time()
{
    fscanf(fp, "%lu", &InterruptLatency);  // I am reading the data from kernel which is not shown here
    measurements[17] = InterrupLatency;

    // after storing it in buffer I am sending the data from but to another layer
}
```

Is it possible read the variable values (s64 and s32) and store it in uint32 Interrup latency ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [incompatible type C error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336289/incompatible-type-c-error)

Comment: @unwind: This is not duplicate, although it is **looking** very similar, the question is a different one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) to copy a string. Operator `=` doesn't work for strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want to do here but using a union may get you somewhere.

```
typedef union
{
    uint8 measurements[32];
    char buf[256];
} measBuf;

measBuf myMeasBuf;
myMeasBuf.measurements[17] = InterrupLatency;
//send myMeasBuf.buf to somewhere
```

To be clear - using a union may not be what you want and yould be highly unstable since there is some system dependencie here. Also the sizes dont match the way that i have written it. In general unions may help you here but you have to see if you can make this work for your usecase.